# Rails: How to use Capybara to test a link's href-value without caring about the text?

Tags: capybara

Capybara provides a useful method to check a link:

```
have_link
```

which as far as I can tell can be used like:

```
have_link("link_text", :href => "actual link")
```

However, I don't care about the link_text, rather I just want to check `href` (as linking the test to the text is more brittle). If I only want to check the `href` this would be a view test.

How do I use Capybara to check the `href` without needing to check the text? Maybe i can use regex?

[edit] changed wording based on answer below

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To find a link based on just its href using capybara you could do

```
link = page.find(:css, 'a[href="actual link"]')
```

or if you're looking to assert that the element exists

```
page.assert_selector(:css, 'a[href="actual link"]')
```

or - if using RSpec

```
expect(page).to have_selector(:css, 'a[href="actual link"]')
```

Since have link by default searches for substrings in the link text you can also do

```
expect(page).to have_link(nil, href: 'actual link')
```

or

```
page.assert_selector(:link, nil, href: 'actual link')
```

Comment: The nil syntax doesn't work for me... anyone else get this?

Answer (score 11):

While looking to the same answer I found out that it's possible to pass options to first argument of `have_link` because it's implementation is:

```
# RSpec matcher for links
# See {Capybara::Node::Matchers#has_link?}
def have_link(locator=nil, options={}, &optional_filter_block)
  locator, options = nil, locator if locator.is_a? Hash
  HaveSelector.new(:link, locator, options, &optional_filter_block)
end
```

So if you don't care about link text you can safely omit first parameter and do this (RSpec syntax):

```
expect(page).to have_link(href: 'some url')
# or even
expect(page).to have_link(href: /some url regexp/)
```